# Python wrapper for QVTKWidget2

Tags: python, qt5, wrapper, vtk, pyqt5

I want to use `VTK 7.0.0` and `Qt5` via its [Python Wrappers](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Python_Wrapping_FAQ).

In `C++` I normally use `QVTKWidget2` instead of `QVTKWidget`, in order to work around
[this problem rendering with intel i915 driver on Linux](http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/vtk-developers/2014-May/014998.html)

[Some examples](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Python/Widgets/EmbedPyQt) on `VTK+Qt+Python` suggest to use the class `QVTKRenderWindowInteractor`, but I encounter the same rendering problem.

Digging in the source tree of `VTK`, I can see [examples using QVTKWidget2 from Python](https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/blob/v7.0.0/GUISupport/Qt/Testing/Python/TestQVTKWidget2.py), but I cannot find the class `vtk.QVTKWidget2` after compiling VTK with the Python wrappers enabled.

Does anybody know how to compile the wrapper for `QVTKWidget2`, or how to work around the i915 rendering problem with `QVTKRenderWindowInteractor`?

Many thanks

Comment: The source for the `QVTKWidget2` class is in src/GUISupport/QtOpenGL, and shows that is a subclass of `QGLWidget`. So you will need OpenGL installed in order to compile it all properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the `QVTKWidgetX` Python wrappers [are not maintained anymore](http://www.vtk.org/pipermail/vtkusers/2013-November/082045.html).

Nevertheless, I was able to embed `VTK` in `qt5` from Python, **without the intel i915 rendering problem**, using a modified version of the class `QVTKRenderWindowInteractor`: I just made it inherit from `QGLWidget` instead of `QWidget`, in the same way that `QVTKWidget2` uses `QGLWidget` as its base class and `QVTKWidget` uses `QWidget`.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing to enable the CMake flag
Module_vtkGUISupportQtOpenGL
If you use the CMake GUI, it's hidden by default as it is an advanced option...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried that flag and still no luck. It seems to me that the wrappers for QVTKWidget are no longer maintained.

Comment: Ah, sorry to ear that. I don't use Python though. but that's the way to get access to QVTKWidget2 in C++. You should ask the mailing list, maybe someone kind enough will answer there